# Ошибка при сохранении изображения в поле с типом BYTEA Postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Хочу сохранить изображение в в колонку с типом BYTEA с помощью `psycopg2`.
Вот строчка, которая отвечает за бинарное изображение:

```
 f"{file_fields['file_data']},"
```

Я в SQL не очень силён и предположил, что возможно мне нужны кавычки для передачи данных и попробовал сделать вот такой вариант:

```
 f"'{file_fields['file_data']}',"
```

При попытке сохранения без кавычек выдаёт следующее:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ".5"
LINE 1: ...b9\x9f\x01D\x91\x0c\x192\xb8\x9f\x00\x00\x00\xd2\'.5\x90\x1e...
                                                             ^
```

А в варианте с кавычками следующее:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: ...3a','fd.png','image/png','86510','(2579, 700)','b'\x89PNG\r\...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Добрый совет. Не храните изображения в БД. Храните в БД пути к файлам изображений.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from psycopg2 import connect

conn = connect(
    '***********************************'
)

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(
    """
    create table if not exists images
    (
        id   smallserial,
        data bytea
    );
    """
)

with open('2022-01-29_004141.png', 'rb') as img:

    cur.execute(
        """
        insert into public.images (data) values (%s);
        """,
        [img.read()]
    )
    conn.commit()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]